# How to get raw sql from SqlAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following code that batch inserts multiple rows into a table.

```
session = SessionManager.maker()
session.bulk_insert_mappings(mappings=insertion_dict_values, mapper=self.model)
session.commit()
session.close()
```

I want to see the raw sql statement that bulk_insert_mapping generates. I've tried setting echo=True:

```
create_engine(db_url, echo=True)
```

The best that I've gotten from the logs is something like:

```
INSERT INTO bogs (created_at, updated_at, address, foo, bar, baz) VALUES (%(created_at_m0)s, %(updated_at_m0)s, %(address_m0)s, %(foo_m0)s, %(bar_m0)s, %(baz_m0)s), (%(created_at_m1)s, %(updated_at_m1)s, %(address_m1)s, %(foo_m1)s, %(bar_m1)s, %(baz_m1)s), (%(created_at_m2)s, %(updated_at_m2)s, %(address_m2)s, %(foo_m2)s, %(bar_m2)s, %(baz_m2)s), (%(created_at_m3)s, %(updated_at_m3)s, %(address_m3)s, %(foo_m3)s, %(bar_m3)s, %(baz_m3)s), (%(created_at_m4)s, %(updated_at_m4)s, %(address_m4)s, %(foo_m4)s, %(bar_m4)s, %(baz_m4)s), (%(created_at_m5)s, %(updated_at_m5)s, %(address_m5)s, %(foo_m5)s, %(bar_m5)s, %(baz_m5)s), (%(created_at_m6)s, %(updated_at_m6)s, %(address_m6)s, %(foo_m6)s, %(bar_m6)s, %(baz_m6)s), (%(created_at_m7)s, %(updated_at_m7)s, %(address_m7)s, %(foo_m7)s, %(bar_m7)s, %(baz_m7)s), (%(created_at_m8)s, %(updated_at_m8)s, %(address_m8)s, %(foo_m8)s, %(bar_m8)s, %(baz_m8)s), (%(created_at_m9)s, %(updated_at_m9)s, %(address_m9)s, %(foo_m9)s, %(bar_m9)s, %(baz_m9)s) RETURNING bogs.created_at, bogs.updated_at, bogs.id, bogs.address, bogs.foo, bogs.bar, bogs.baz
```

This looks close to the raw sql statement but it's not quite there (i.e. values should already be interpolated).

Is there a way to get the actual sql statement that gets sent to postgres?